# When i make build using npm run build <router-view /> is not default rendering

Tags: vue.js, routes, production

[without build its works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa3sU.png)

This is my routes code here...

```
import cards from '../pages/cards.vue';
import PercentageCalculator from '../pages/PercentageCalculator.vue'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: cards
  },
  { path: '/percentage-calculator', component: PercentageCalculator }
]
```

This is my vue.config.js file here..

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? './'
    : '/'
}
```

[Here is screenshot of when i am try to run build index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nIOP.png)

Comment: Maybe try to import your routes with `@/pages/cards` and revert your vue config to '/'

Comment: @Abregre not works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.